# GDB find string strange results

Tags: debugging, gdb, memory, strings

I'm playing with gdb and strange things are happening. I wanted to find some address in memory where string "/bin/sh" is located, and gdb says it found it. But when I examine the memory there, the string there is totally different.

Can you please help me to find out what this behaviour means, and how can I really find the adress of the string?

```
(gdb) find 0xb7ecffb0,+999999, "/bin/sh"
0xb7fba23f
1 pattern found.
(gdb) x/s 0xb7fba23f
0xb7fba23f:  "KIND in __gen_tempname\""
```

Comment: Protostar 6? I'm getting exactly the same problem. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

GDB couldn't find real strings most of the time. But, you can find the offset of the string from the local object file and adjust it with dynamic loading information.

From `info proc map`:

```
Mapped address spaces:

Start Addr   End Addr       Size     Offset objfile
 0x8048000  0x8049000     0x1000          0        /opt/protostar/bin/stack6
 0x8049000  0x804a000     0x1000          0        /opt/protostar/bin/stack6
 0x804a000  0x806b000    0x21000          0           [heap]
0xb7e96000 0xb7e97000     0x1000          0        
0xb7e97000 0xb7fd5000   0x13e000          0         /lib/libc-2.11.2.so
0xb7fd5000 0xb7fd6000     0x1000   0x13e000         /lib/libc-2.11.2.so
0xb7fd6000 0xb7fd8000     0x2000   0x13e000         /lib/libc-2.11.2.so
0xb7fd8000 0xb7fd9000     0x1000   0x140000         /lib/libc-2.11.2.so
                                      ...
```

And from `/lib/libc-2.11.2.so` file:

```
user@protostar:/opt/protostar/bin$ xxd -u /lib/libc-2.11.2.so |grep -B 1 bin/sh
011f3b0: 6600 696E 6974 7900 6E61 6E00 2D63 002F  f.inity.nan.-c./
011f3c0: 6269 6E2F 7368 0065 7869 7420 3000 6361  bin/sh.exit 0.ca
```

Use this info to find static address of `/bin/sh` string in virtual address space:

```
(gdb) x/s 0xb7e97000+0x011f3bf
0xb7fb63bf:  "/bin/sh"
```

I know this is not an answer to your first question about why GDB find shows this behavior when finding strings. I couldn't find anything about that. I used Protostar Stack6 challenge binary and exploit-exercises-protostar-2.iso environment, so addresses must be the same. There is also `/bin/csh` string in the same shared object file. You can try to find that address using this method.